# htaccess trim numbers from end url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a lot of urls that contain a 13 digit numeric code at the end, looking like…

```
http://www.example.com/a-test-title-1/1579845887463/
http://www.example.com/a-test-title-2/2356668749876/
http://www.example.com/a-test-title-3/5689874598235/
```

I would like to remove these numbers so the urls look like…

```
http://www.example.com/a-test-title-1/
http://www.example.com/a-test-title-2/
http://www.example.com/a-test-title-3/
```

I've tried this in my htaccess file `RewriteRule [0-9]{10,15} $1 [R=301,L]` but it's not working and I don't know what to do?

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chop the number off with this RewriteRule

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+?/)\d+/$ $1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Perfect Olaf!

I've just written something very similar which appears to work OK…

    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\/[0-9]{10,}\/$
    RewriteRule .* %1\/ [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

I've written this which appears to work OK. Can anyone spot any glaring errors?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\/[0-9]{10,}\/$
RewriteRule .* %1\/ [R=301,L]`
```

Comment: You don't need to escape the slashes `/` and you might want to anchor at the beginning of the string `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/[0-9]{10,}/$`. But besides my nitpicking, this looks good. :-)